# upgrade to PHP 8 using Homebrew Error on macOS Big Sur

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I want to upgrade to PHP 8 with Homebrew on Mac (macOS Big Sur Version: 11.2)
But there is a problem!

1- Show my version of PHP:

```
TERMINAL:
MyUser@MacBook-Pro ~ % php -v
WARNING: PHP is not recommended
PHP is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
Future versions of macOS will not include PHP.
PHP 7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS) (cli) (built: Dec 21 2020 21:33:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.24, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

2- Install version 8 of PHP:

```
MyUser@MacBook-Pro ~ % brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.0
Warning: shivammathur/php/php 8.0.2 is already installed, it's just not linked.
To link this version, run:
brew link php
```

3- Brew Link PHP:

```
MyUser@MacBook-Pro ~ % brew link --overwrite --force php@8.0
Error: Formulae found in multiple taps:
    * shivammathur/php/php@5.6
    * exolnet/deprecated/php@5.6

Please use the fully-qualified name (e.g. shivammathur/php/php@5.6) to refer to the formula.
```

**How to solve this problem?**

Comment: Just a small question, why would you tap from 3rd party while brew has it's own official release of PHP 8? It seems like you were trying out experimenting brew with guidance from different location. Have you solved the issue already?

Answer (score 2):

You have to untap this deprecated version.

```
brew untap exolnet/homebrew-deprecated
```

Afterwards you can link a new PHP version.

Comment: oh my god finally some good answer, thank you very much